# Why i can not use personalDetails() variable for printing

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

I wanted to print `personalDetails()` variables in `printingPersonalDeatils()` and I am getting

> NameError: name 'name' is not defined`

My code:

```
class Programmer:
        company="Microsoft"
    
        def personalDetails(self):
            name=input("Enter name : ")
            age=int(input("Enter age : "))
            role=input("Enter role of employee : ")
            salary=int(input("Enter salary : "))
    
        def printingPersonalDetails(self):
            print(f"{name} {age} {role} {salary}")
    
object1 = Programmer()
object1.personalDetails()
object1.printingPersonalDetails()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Programmer:
    company = "Microsoft"

    def personalDetails(self):
        self.name = input("Enter name : ")
        self.age = int(input("Enter age : "))
        self.role = input("Enter role of employee : ")
        self.salary = int(input("Enter salary : "))

    def printingPersonalDetails(self):
        print(f"{self.name} {self.age} {self.role} {self.salary}")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Programmer** is a class and **personalDetails** is a function inside it. So whatever you define inside a function its scope is limited to that function itself. To make the variables accessible globally, you need to use `self` keyword.

Here `self` means class object itself. So now you can access the variables with the reference of class object like below, or you can access the object outside the class also.

**Refer:** [Access modifier in Python](https://www.studytonight.com/python/access-modifier-python)

```
class Programmer:
        company="Microsoft"
    
        def personalDetails(self):
            self.name=input("Enter name : ")
            self.age=int(input("Enter age : "))
            self.role=input("Enter role of employee : ")
            self.salary=int(input("Enter salary : "))
    
        def printingPersonalDetails(self):
            print(self.name + " is " + str(self.age) + " years old. He is a " + self.role + " and he is earning total $" + str(self.salary) + " per month.")
    
object1 = Programmer()
object1.personalDetails()
object1.printingPersonalDetails()
```